# Fire a change function without changing focus

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a table that is sortable and filterable, and everything works fine if I change my filter using a select field. But, if a user doesn't select a filter after x number of seconds, I want it to filter based on a designated option. I have no problem changing the selection after a set time, but the javascript to filter doesn't recognize this is a change() event. How can I get it to recognize it as a change, or by some other way register the default selection after a set period of time?

For reference, I'm using this script for the table filtering/sorting:

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/

I'd like to pass it my own values for Table.filter(this,this).

Comment: Just call the same function that you call in the `onchange` handler.

Comment: @Barmar this is probably going to sound stupid, so I apologize. I'm using a script I found online, that uses the following to sort: 

    select id="select" onchange="Table.filter(this,this)"

how would I reference (this, this) since I assume that's dependent upon the selection? Not only that, I have no idea what this,this is referring to.

Comment: Please add a link to the website that describes the table script.

Comment: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/table/

Comment: That function requires a reference to the `select` field, you need a function that lets you supply an arbitrary filter criteria. So I need to check the documentation to see if it has that capability.

Comment: Looking at the source code, some kind of filter expression can be passed as the second argument instead of `this`. But this feature doesn't seem to be explained in the documentation, it doesn't show how to call `Table.filter` at all.

Comment: Actually, 'this' in that case refers to the select itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
var defaultFilter = 3;
var filterTimeout = 5000;

window.setTimeout(function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("select");
    select.selectedIndex = defaultFilter;
    Table.filter(select, select);
}, filterTimeout);
```

Comment: Definitely very close! It "filters", but it filters everything (i.e., the table displays no rows).

Comment: Did you set the default to a valid index in the select dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

`<select id="select" onchange="Table.filter(this,this)">... </select>`

Javascript:

```
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var secondsToChange = 2;

select.onclick = function() {
  window.setTimeout(function(){select.onchange.apply(select)},secondsToChange*1000);
};
```

I think that should work...